# C preprocessor compute max sizeof structures

Tags: c, struct, c-preprocessor, sizeof, unions

I have a buffer pool of structures that look something like this simplified example:

```
struct astruct {
    int     c1;
    int     c2;
    union {
        atype1  u1;
        atype2  u2;
        atype3  u3;
    } u;
};
```

Now, I realize that one of the union types, say `atype1`, is much larger than the others. I want to split my buffer pool into 2 separate pools, one with blocks of memory equal to `sizeof(astruct)` and the other with blocks of memory large enough to hold the same structure if it did not include the `u1` member, which for above would be

```
offsetof(astruct,u) + MAX(sizeof(atype2),sizeof(atype3))
```

How can I get the preprocessor to compute the `MAX(sizeof,...)`, supposing there are really about a dozen different union types?  Or, is there a nice clean readable way to get the preprocessor to manufacture the different variants on the structure?

Comment: The preprocessor doesn't know anything about structs, unions, data types, or sizeof.  All if does is handle macros and include files, and conditional compilation.

Comment: Personally, I would decouple storage from representation and create specialized' astruct_u1' and 'astruct_u2u3' structures just for storage. Upon retrieval, the routine could re-assemble the general 'astruct' structure.

Comment: @Lars, yes, this is exactly what I would do if I had thought ahead to put the common elements, c1,c2 (in reality many more) into a substructure.  Then it would be easy enough to re-use that structure to create the different variants.  I could do that now, but not sure I want to change all the code that references the current structure.

Comment: "Now, I realize that one of the union types, say atype1, is much larger than the others."  Hold right there. This means that something about your program design doesn't make sense at all. If `atype1` is much larger than the other types in the union, then why are they in a union together to begin with? Are you trying to use the same memory for unrelated purposes (very bad idea)? Or are you trying to program a "variant" (bad idea)? You should probably consider remaking that structure from scratch.

Comment: @Lundin, they are in the union because a lot of processing depends only on the leading common fields and initially I thought the specific elements would be of similar size, so managed from common buffer pool.  But, you are right, I would do this differently if I redid it.  I would put the common fields in one struct, and then define a different struct beginning with that struct for each variant.  Then typecast back and forth between the common and the specific variant as needed.  The union makes it too easy to refer to a field that is not actually in use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a way. It is somewhat clumsy, but it works. You may need to adapt this a bit.

---

First create a header file `structdef.h`:

```
struct STRUCT_NAME {
    int     c1;
    int     c2;
    union {
#if WANT_ATYPE & 1
        atype1  u1;
#endif
#if WANT_ATYPE & 2
        atype2  u2;
#endif
#if WANT_ATYPE & 4
        atype3  u3;
#endif
    } u;
};

#undef WANT_ATYPE
#undef STRUCT_NAME
```

---

Now create a file `structall.h`:

```
#define WANT_ATYPE  (0x01 | 0x02 | 0x4)
#define STRUCT_NAME struct123
#include <structdef.h>

#define WANT_ATYPE  (0x02 | 0x4)
#define STRUCT_NAME struct23
#include <structdef.h>

#define WANT_ATYPE  (0x4)
#define STRUCT_NAME struct3
#include <structdef.h>
```

---

That will define things the way you want. You're done.

But, to show you what it looks like, here is the output of `cpp -E -P structall.h -I.`:

```
struct struct123 {
    int c1;
    int c2;
    union {
        atype1 u1;
        atype2 u2;
        atype3 u3;
    } u;
};
struct struct23 {
    int c1;
    int c2;
    union {
        atype2 u2;
        atype3 u3;
    } u;
};
struct struct3 {
    int c1;
    int c2;
    union {
        atype3 u3;
    } u;
};
```

Comment: Thanks, that should work.  I don't like keeping track of the bitfield correspondence, but, since I really only need 2 variants, I can simplify the basic technique.

Comment: You're welcome. Did the bitfield thing just for brevity. Normally, I'd do `#ifdef WANT_ATYPE1`, `#ifdef WANT_ATYPE2`, etc. What I did is actually an _old_ technique [before the high falutin' c++ templates showed up :-)]. To put a modern spin on it, just tell everybody you're _not_ using the preprocessor but doing _metaprogramming_ :-).

Answer (score 1):

This can be done without a separate include file, if you don't mind inserting a bunch of backslashes. But read the warning below, which also applies to Craig Estey's less backslash-intensive solution.

```
#define INCLUDE(x) x
#define IGNORE(x)
#define STRUCT(NAME, VARIANT) \
struct NAME {                 \
  int     c1;                 \
  int     c2;                 \
  union {                     \
    VARIANT(char u1;)         \
    short u2;                 \
    char u3[100];             \
  } u;                        \
}

STRUCT(astruct, INCLUDE);
#define SHORTER sizeof(STRUCT(,IGNORE))
```

([live on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2548c473847e9493), with a small difference)

But **beware**: if the alignment of the union member is conditioned by the alignment of the potentially omitted element and not by the common prefix, then omitting the element could reduce the padding before the union, and you will then get the wrong size. See [this snippet on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/42e9c6fe525056e4) where `u3` was changed to a `long double` with the result that the size computed as `SHORTER` is actually less than the offset of the union, which will result in not enough space being allocated for the shorter pool.